# Reading from new folders every x seconds and using their data

Tags: java, loops, filesystems

Currently I am writing an application in java that looks through the files in a directory (call it 'topics'). Within this directory are some number of folders named after their respective topics, maybe 'dog', 'cat', etc.

I am currently using a ScheduledExecutorService to look through this directory every 30 seconds, going through each topic folder and performing some operation on the contents with in the folder (We'll say some other independent piece of code is writing something to these topic folders, maybe a log file or something).

What would be the best way to only examine the new subdirectories each 30 seconds? If I start with just the topic dog, and somewhere between those 30 seconds the topics 'cat' and 'bird' are added, what would be the best way for me to only look through those new folders? I was thinking about comparing it to a HashSet or something, but I'm not sure what the most efficient way it would be to do this.

I ask because there could potentially be a great amount of subdirectories being created, and it seems to me problematic to try to loop through each one with something like directory.listFiles(). Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

Use java's WatchService API.

> The WatchService API is fairly low level, allowing you to customize it. You can use it as is, or you can choose to create a high-level API on top of this mechanism so that it is suited to your particular needs. - [Java Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html)

When WatchService detects a file or directory change it can notify you of watch file or directory was changed giving you the path to it. By using this api you don't have to worry about comparing two lists to see what was changed because the api provides the path of the changed file.

Take a look at this Java Tutorial "[Watching a Directory for Changes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html)" by Oracle on using the WatchService api.